# Auto scroll into my last ListView item added lead to InvalidoperationException

Tags: wpf, listview

I have this collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> files { get; set; }
```

Subscride into `CollectionChanged` event:

```
files.CollectionChanged += files_CollectionChanged;
```

And when new item added into my `ListView`:

```
    private void files_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                listView.ItemsSource = files;
                listView.SelectedIndex = listView.Items.Count - 1;
                listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);
            }
        }));
    }
```

The reason i am doing this is that i want to see the files added and the auto scroll over the last added item.

So the result is `InvalidoperationException`:

> An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.   See the inner
>   exception for more information.

**Update**

Inner exception:

{"Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):\r\nThis exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:6' with name 'listView' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:\r\n  Accumulated count 2 is different from actual count 6.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]\r\n\r\nOne or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:\r\n     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator\r\n      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection\r\n       System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView\r\n        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[app name, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]\r\n(The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)\r\n\r\nThe most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.\r\n\r\nThe exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:\n   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)\r\nfrom the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.\r\n"}

The exception occurs because this line (when remove this all good):

```
listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: I think you meant WPF instead. If yes then edit your post and add proper tag.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, updated.

Comment: What in inner exception? Where exception arise?

Comment: Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the scrolling into view from setting the currently selected item.

Hookup the ListView SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" and implement as follows:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    Selector selector = sender as Selector;
    ListView listView = selector as ListView;
    if ( listView != null && selector.SelectedItem != null )
    {
        listView.ScrollIntoView( selector.SelectedItem );
    }
}
```

For the ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged :

```
private void OnCollectionChanged( object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs )
{
    if ( notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems != null )
    {
        var newItem = notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems.Cast<MyData>().LastOrDefault();
        if ( newItem != null )
        {
            listView.SelectedItem = newItem;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you're changing the listView.ItemsSource every time the collection changes. Seems like you'd normally just do that when you new up or set the ObservableCollection.